# Is it possible and how to implement selects using Jackcess?

Tags: java, jackcess

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to use **`select`** in the **jackcess (v3.0.0)**. 
I have a database from which I would like to display items in the range from x to y. It is possible to write this in jackcess? I search in documentation of jackces something about queries but only what i find is something like this - **`public List<String> getFromTables()`** but don't know how to implement's it. 
Before, i used ucanaccess library, but this one table didn't want to show the results and only displayed warnings.

The samplest select i need to write:

```
select MAX(X_ID+1) from TABLENAME t1 where X_ID> 500000 and X_ID< 1000000"
            + "and not exists (select 1 from TABLENAME t2 where t2.X_ID=t1.X_ID+1)";
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Jackcess does not provide any support for executing selects like this on the data. The "query" in the documentation likely refer to the fact that MS Access DB can contain defined queries that can be the base for more advanced functionality in access itself.

Jackcess mostly only provides a simple read/write interface, so you will probably look for some ODBC-JDBC driver/bridge to allow executing normal JDBC queries.

Also http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html sounds interesting, although I did not try it myself yet.

Comment: Relevant entry from the FAQ: https://jackcess.sourceforge.io/faq.html#query